# Как объединить css selector java

Tags: java, java-stream

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть, например,

```
@FindBy(css = ".mer_name")
public List<WebElement> listMer; // название

@FindBy(css = ".mer_time")
public List<WebElement> listMerDate; // дата мероприятия
```

Как все впихнуть в один ArrayList или `List<Webelement>`?

P.S. оба селектора находятся на 1 странице и относятся к одному мероприятию

Answer (score 0):

Объединить два списка при помощи Java Stream API можно при помощи `Stream::concat`:

```java
List<WebElement> result = Stream.concat(
        listMer.stream(), listMerDate.stream()
    ) // Stream<WebElement>
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // или toList() для Java 16+
```

Аналогично можно использовать `Stream.of + Stream.flatMap`, особенно если нужно объединить более двух списков:

```java
List<WebElement> result = Stream.of(
        listMer, listMerDate
    ) // Stream<List<WebElement>>
    .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<WebElement>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, можно проголосовать и/или отметить его как решение, поставив галочку.